# Internet Explorer Automation Internal website

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, vba, automation

My company has an internal website where we get a lot of information. I believe the site uses active directory for authentication. I want to use vba/excel to automate the browser and get the data. The following code works just fine for other sites like Google but not our site. The code will load oursite but errors after that.

```
Sub GetData()
Dim WP As Object
Dim DC As Object
Dim OB As Object
Set WP = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
WP.Visible = True
WP.Navigate "http://OurSite/Shared/QueryFarm.aspx?queryid=1"
Do While WP.Busy = True
Loop
Set DC = WP.Document 'ERROR HERE
Set OB = DC.getElementsByName("__CS__")
OB(0).Value = "Search"
WP.Quit
End Sub
```

I get "automation/unspecified error" on `set dc = wp.document`. I've tryed doing this...

```
Set OB = wp.document.getElementsByName("__CS__")
```

I've also tried changing the object types to `InternetExplorer` and `HTMLInputElement` and `HTMLDocument`.

I managed to do this in the past but it's been a long time and I didn't save the code. Now I'm struggling.

Is active directory making this impossible? Am I missing a setting/parameter?

Comment: Try also checking `WP.ReadyState` in your `Do...Loop` - typically it's not enough to only check `WP.Busy`

Comment: I'll try it but I've stepped through and aloud it lots if time to load.

Comment: I can't seem to load the website itself. Are you sure the page is working?

Comment: @VBAProgrammer - OP stated the site is internal.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Sub GetData()
Dim WP As Object
Dim DC As Object
Dim OB As Object

    Set WP = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    WP.Visible = True
    WP.Navigate "http://OurSite/Shared/QueryFarm.aspx?queryid=1"

    WaitForLoad WP

    Set DC = WP.Document         
    Set OB = DC.getElementsByName("__CS__")
    OB(0).Value = "Search"
    'WP.Quit

End Sub

Sub WaitForLoad(IE as object)
    Do While IE.Busy = True or IE.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually found out that it was a security thing. After making some changes in the internet-setting/security it seems to work fine. However, I'm not sure what exactly is going on because I put all the setting back it it sill works.